# ANTLR Parser with manual lexer

Tags: c#, antlr, lexer, parser-generator

I'm migrating a C#-based programming language compiler from a manual lexer/parser to Antlr.

Antlr has been giving me severe headaches because it usually *mostly* works, but then there are the small parts that do not and are incredibly painful to solve.

I discovered that most of my headaches are caused by the lexer parts of Antlr, rather than the parser. Then I noticed `parser grammar X;` and realized that perhaps I could have my manually written lexer and then an Antlr generated parser.

So I'm looking for more documentation on this topic. I guess a custom ITokenStream could work, but there appears to be virtually no online documentation on this topic...

Comment: My recommendation is that you can learn from the existing ones. However, I can only find NHibernate who uses Antlr, and the usage is rather limited. :(

Comment: *"but then there are the small parts that do not and are incredibly painful to solve"* - Odd. The lexing part of a language is usually easier to implement. Perhaps you could explain what "small parts" are giving you problems?

Comment: @Bart Kiers I'm having trouble with implementing ranges and a few other features (such as 3.toString() and 3.0.toString())in a different way than that listed in their FAQ. These kind of problems are incredibly simple to solve in a manually created lexer.

Comment: sorry but I have no idea what *"trouble with implementing ranges"* and *"other features (such as 3.toString() and 3.0.toString())"* mean. I also don't know what *"their FAQ"* is. There is no need to explain yourself if you're not looking for a way to do this in ANTLR, but if you are interested, please edit your original question explain what it is you're not able to do in a ANTLR lexer.

Comment: @Bart Kiers Right now, I found my answer so I'm pretty satisfied. If I do want to explore the possibilities of using an Antlr-generated lexer, then I'll be sure to post a separated question. But, btw, "their FAQ" means "Antlr's FAQ", ranges means stuff like "1..2", and 3.toString()/3.0.toString() means exactly that: Obtaining a field(or, in this case) method of a number without having Antlr die horribly on the multiple possible meanings of '.'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out how. It might not be the best approach but it certainly seems to be working.

1. Antlr parsers receive a `ITokenStream` parameter
2. Antlr lexers are themselves `ITokenSource`s
3. `ITokenSource` is a significantly simpler interface than `ITokenStream`
4. The simplest way to convert a `ITokenSource` to a `ITokenStream` is to use a `CommonSourceStream`, which receives a `ITokenSource` parameter

So now we only need to do 2 things:

1. Adjust the grammar to be parser-only
2. Implement ITokenSource

Adjusting the grammar is very simple. Simply remove all lexer declarations and ensure you declare the grammar as `parser grammar`. A simple example is posted here for convinience:

```
parser grammar mygrammar;

options
{
    language=CSharp2;
}

@parser::namespace { MyNamespace }

document:   (WORD {Console.WriteLine($WORD.text);} |
        NUMBER {Console.WriteLine($NUMBER.text);})*;
```

Note that the following file will output `class mygrammar` instead of `class mygrammarParser`.

So now we want to implement a "fake" lexer.
I personally used the following pseudo-code:

```
TokenQueue q = new TokenQueue();
//Do normal lexer stuff and output to q
CommonTokenStream cts = new CommonTokenStream(q);
mygrammar g = new mygrammar(cts);
g.document();
```

Finally, we need to define `TokenQueue`. `TokenQueue` is not strictly necessary but I used it for convenience.
It should have methods to receive the lexer tokens, and methods to output Antlr tokens. So if not using Antlr native tokens one has to implement a convert-to-Antlr-token method.
Also, `TokenQueue` must implement `ITokenSource`.

Be aware that it is very important to correctly set the token variables. Initially, I had some problems because I was miscalculating `CharPositionInLine`. If these variables are incorrectly set, then the parser may fail.
Also, the normal channel(not hidden) is 0.

This seems to be working for me so far. I hope others find it useful as well.
I'm open to feedback. In particular, if you find a better way to solve this problem, feel free to post a separate reply.

Comment: nice work, how did you handle the .tokens file ? I am trying to do something similar except use pygments lexers

Comment: @Naveen I don't remember doing anything to the .tokens file at all.

Comment: I got your method to work as well with python.  Others have used with with jflex and stax.  I have posted a simple example on github: https://github.com/tinku99/antlr-pygments