# Writing a custom Xtext/ANTLR lexer without a grammar file

Tags: antlr, lexer, xtext

I'm writing an Eclipse/Xtext plugin for CoffeeScript, and I realized I'll probably need to write a lexer for it by hand.  CoffeeScript parser also uses a [hand-written lexer](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/src/lexer.coffee) to handle indentation and other tricks in the grammar.

Xtext generates a class that extends `org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.Lexer` which in turn extends `org.antlr.runtime.Lexer`.  So I suppose I'll have extend it.  I can see two ways to do that

- Override `mTokens()`.  This is done by the generated code, changing the internal state.
- Override `nextToken()` which seems a natural approach, but then I'll have to keep track of the internal state.

I couldn't find any example how to write even a simple lexer for ANTLR without a grammar file.  So the easiest answer would be a pointer to one.

An answer to [Xtext: grammar for language with significant/semantic whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167834/xtext-grammar-for-language-with-significant-semantic-whitespace) refers to [todotext](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/todotext/) which handles the problem of indentation by changing the tokens in the underlying input stream.  I don't want to go that way, because it would be difficult to handle other tricks of the coffeescript grammar.

UPDATE:

I realized in the meantime that my question was partly Xtext specific.

Comment: You just need to implement `ITokenSource` - and do whatever you need to do in the `nextToken` method. Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414166/antlr-parser-with-manual-lexer There are examples on handling indentation (in Python, for instance) in the Definitive Antlr Reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what I did -- and it works.

```
public class MyLexer extends myprj.parser.antlr.internal.InternalMylangLexer {
  private SomeExternalLexer externalLexer;

  public Lexer(CharStream in) {
    super(in);
    externalLexer = new SomeExternalLexer(in);
  }

  @Override
  public Token nextToken() {
    Token token = null;
    ExternalToken extToken = null;
    try {
      extToken = externalLexer.nextToken();
      if (extToken == null) {
        token = CommonToken.INVALID_TOKEN;
      }
      else {
        token = mapExternalToken(extToken);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      token = CommonToken.INVALID_TOKEN;
    }
    return token;
  }

  protected Token mapExternalToken(ExternalToken extToken) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then I have a slightly customized parser containing:

```
public class BetterParser extends MylangParser {
  @Override
  protected TokenSource createLexer(CharStream stream) {
    MyLexer lexer = new MyLexer(stream);
    return lexer;
  }
}
```

I also had to change my `MylangRuntimeModule.java` to contain this method

```
@Override
public Class<? extends org.eclipse.xtext.parser.IParser> bindIParser() {
     return myprj.parser.BetterParser.class ;
}
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 6):

Another way (without the need to create a custom parser) is to create a custom lexer by extending Xtext's lexer (org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.Lexer) as follows:

```
public class CustomSTLexer extends Lexer {

    @Override
    public void mTokens() {
      // implement lexer here
    }
}
```

Then you bind it in your module:

```
@Override
public void configureRuntimeLexer(Binder binder) {
    binder.bind(Lexer.class)
                .annotatedWith(Names.named(LexerBindings.RUNTIME))
                .to(CustomSTLexer.class);
}
```

If you want to have a look at a complete example, I have implemented a custom lexer for an Xtext-based editor for StringTemplate called [hastee](http://sourceforge.net/p/hastee/git/ci/71ba301f4a3829b9b43ea88b027dbdb06acc8676/tree/plugins/net.sf.hastee/src/net/sf/hastee/CustomSTLexer.java).